# unable to download a model for Polish for Spacy

Tags: python, model, spacy

I am trying to program in Python but I have no background in programing.

I would like to parse a Polish text using the Spacy parser but I am having problems downloading the model for Polish. I have copied the commands form the Spacey webpage: https://spacy.io/models, but I am getting a syntax error on the first line.

I would be appreciate a hint how to solve this problem, which is probably very basic. I would be grateful for an explanation for a "dummy".

Here is the code:

```
python -m spacy download pl_core_news_lg
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("pl_core_news_lg")
```

And here is the Error message:

```
File "<ipython-input-16-4475fd4a4fdb>", line 3
    python -m spacy download pl_core_news_lg
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `python -m spacy download pl_core_news_lg` must be run from your terminal (`cmd`, "wiersz polecenia"). Launch the `cmd` with admin privileges.

Answer (score -1):

You're pasting the code in ipython, but in ipython all the code needs to be Python code.

The first line is not Python code, it's a terminal command. You can run it in ipython by starting the line with an exclamation point (`!`).

This is very basic, but also very hard to figure out from scratch. You might want to go through a tutorial for basic Python notebook usage first, or ask for more support if you're in an office or school setting.